# Google drive api doesn't update/create/delete any file

Tags: google-drive-api

Google drive api doesn't update/create/delete any file, but app authorized using local credentials store.
I used java tutorial from official google samples. Only getters functions work fine.
What can be wrong? No any exception is thrown

```
File file = service.files().get(fileId).execute();

DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date);
file.setDescription("sdgdfgg");
file.setModifiedTime(dateTime);
file.setCreatedTime(dateTime);

service.files().update(fileId, file);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use `execute` after you are calling the `update` method, otherwise you are not making any request:

```
service.files().update(fileId, file).execute();
```

Same goes when you try to create the file.

#### Reference

- [Drive API v3 Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java).